# Mac shut down during update

Tags: macos, software-update, mac-mini, bug

I just tried updating my Mac mini to the latest version of macOS, and when I thought the update was finished, my Mac wouldn’t start up or display any image on my monitor. I shut down my Mac with the power button and when I started it back up it allowed me to log in, but after I put my password in and the loading bar appeared, my Mac screen is now blank where as before it would take me to my desktop. Looks like I maybe accidentally forced-shut it down during an update. Tried restarting it a couple of different times and it’s done the same thing. Is it just finishing up the update now that I’ve logged back in after restarting and that’s why my desktop isn’t loading? There isn’t any loading indicator to show whether or not it’s finishing up the update though so I’m not sure. Not sure what to do here but any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you say the latest, there are [several build versions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/38/2022/3/14/20-21) and channels. I’ll answer in general but knowing what type of Mac (processor) and control chip and what major version, we might offer more detailed guidance.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would decide if your last backup is good. If it is not good or you will lose substantial money or days of work, call an expert to get a backup now before trying to fix it.

Assuming you have a good backup, start here:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156

If you got the log in screen, you are done with the update due to it failing or due to it succeeding so now you have a user account issue most likely.

Assuming you have a recent OS and hardware - does a safe mode start help?

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac